Squash gone wrong, how to revert to origin branch?
I did git rebase -i <commit> to squash the last x commits and they got committed to my local branch. Then realized that I picked the wrong commit for rebase. I made a backup of the files changed in this commit.  Now I want to go back to the version of my branch that is in the remote origin and redo squashing.
How do I do that?

git reset --hard origin/branch-name
